# Can i alter non-Partitioned table with already loaded data to have dynamic partitions?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have tried with using  hive command

insert into table partitioned_table_name partition(partition_col) select * from non-Partitioned table ;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do it. But you need to select correct sequence of columns while inserting.
for example, if your table  structure is like this -

```
create table mytable_patitioned (c1 int, c2 string) partition by c3 int;
```

Then your insert statement should be like below - partition column should be last column in select statement.

```
insert into mytable_patitioned partition(c3) select c1,c2,c3 from non_part_table;
```